# Make [windows-live-mail] a synonym of [outlook.com]

Tags: support, status-completed, tag-synonyms

The Microsoft email service for consumers has changed it's name several times.

We have [windows-live-mail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-live-mail)(25 questions) which should be a synonym of [outlook.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook.com) (249 questions) but as I haven't the 5 rep on the tag, I can't propose the synonym from the synonym page.

There are some recent questions that ask about live.com email address like [How do I get a live.com email address?](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/107426/88163). I think that it will be more beneficial to make [windows-live-mail](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-live-mail) a synonym than to burninate it b/c I think that some users will not think that they should use [outlook.com](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/outlook.com).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All set! Synonymized and merged.

(In addition, [windows-live](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/windows-live) is now synonymized and merged with [office-365](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/office-365))